# Python unicode character codes?

Tags: python, unicode

Is there a way to "insert" a Unicode character into a string in Python 3? For example,

```
>>>import unicode
>>>string = 'This is a full block: %s' % (unicode.charcode(U+2588))
>>>print(string)
This is a full block: █
```

Comment: Your example uses a code point, but you say "character". You should be aware that what most people mean when they say character can correspond to *several* code points.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, with [unicode character escapes](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):

```
print u'This is a full block: \u2588'
```

Comment: … or with `unichr()`, if you want to create a character from a dynamic code point (doesn't seem to be the case here; I added it for completeness).

Comment: If you prefer something more readable, you can use `u'This is a full block: \N{FULL BLOCK}'`.

Comment: Where can I find a list of that names like `FULL BLOCK`?

Comment: @buhtz, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements lists blocks;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols -> http://www.decodeunicode.org/de/u+2580 .  HTH

Comment: Is the number you put after the `\u` decimal, hexadecimal, octal, or what exactly?

Comment: @buhtz: `import unicodedata; unicodedata.name('\u2588')` also works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\udddd` where you replace `dddd` with the the charcode.

```
print u"Foo\u0020bar"
```

Prints

```
Foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \u to escape a Unicode character code:

```
s = u'\u0020'
```

which defines a string containing the space character.