# How to use Unicode characters in a python string

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'd like to be able to use unicode in my python string. For instance I have an icon:

```
icon = '&#x25B2;'
print icon
```

which should create icon = '▲'

but instead it literally returns it in string form: `&#x25B2;`

How can I make this string recognize unicode?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You shoudl adjust the title of your question. The question has nothing to do with utf-8 at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use string escape sequences, as documented in [the “string and bytes literals” section](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-18) of the language reference. For Python 3 this would work simply like this:

```
>>> icon = '\u25b2'
>>> print(icon)
▲
```

In [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-15) this only works within unicode strings. Unicode strings have a `u` prefix before the quotation mark:

```
>>> icon = u'\u25b2'
>>> print icon
▲
```

This is not necessary in Python 3 as all strings in Python 3 are unicode strings.

Answer (score 9):

Python 3:

```
>>> print('\N{BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE}')
▲
```

Python 2:

```
>>> print u'\N{BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE}'
▲
```

Comment: Wow. Did't know that!

Answer (score 2):

Use `\u` escaping in a unicode string literal:

```
>>> print u"\u25B2".encode("utf-8")
▲
```

Alternatively, if you want to use HTML entities, you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/71522

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> icon = '\u25B2'
>>> print(icon)
▲
```

Also refer to: [Python unicode character codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213866/python-unicode-character-codes)